# MySQL - Conditionally build JSON_OBJECT

Tags: mysql, json

Is it possible to conditionally build a json object e.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
      CASE
        WHEN some_condition THEN key, val
        ELSE
           // do nothing 
        END CASE

    );
```

If not, how can I conditionally build a json object. Bascially I only want to inlcude non null properties.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Could you please let me know what's the use case of conditional `keys` in JSON object? Do you understand that the number of object `keys` will be equal or less than the number of conditions?

Comment: @Kosh what is the syntax to achieve this. The code I've posted doesnt seem to work?

Comment: The syntax depends on your exact problem and desired result.

Comment: Seems like something you'd do in a programming language, instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`JSON_MERGE_PATCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch) to merge JSON Objects conditionally.

`JSON_MERGE_PATCH` ignores objects with `NULL` values. So, we can build JSON Objects with `NULL` values wherever the condition fails, else create them normally.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PATCH(

-- Following key will exist because condition is success
JSON_OBJECT('key1', CASE WHEN 1  /* some condition here */  THEN 'value1' ELSE NULL END),
  
-- Following key will not exist because condition fails
JSON_OBJECT('key2', CASE WHEN 0  /* some condition here */  THEN 'value2' ELSE NULL END)
  
) as result;
```

| result |
| --- |
| {"key1": "value1"} |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igejPHZ8HPi9fZH9XzZSZd/0)

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```sql
mysql> SET @`key` = 'key',
    ->     @`val` = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   CASE WHEN @`key` IS NOT NULL AND @`val` IS NOT NULL THEN
    ->     JSON_OBJECT(@`key`, @`val`)
    ->   END `json`;
+------------+
| json       |
+------------+
| {"key": 1} |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`key` = 'key',
    ->     @`val` = NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   CASE WHEN @`key` IS NOT NULL AND @`val` IS NOT NULL THEN
    ->     JSON_OBJECT(@`key`, @`val`)
    ->   END `json`;
+------+
| json |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```